# How to get registration id in push event in ServiceWorker?

Tags: service-worker

I have the registration id when subscribing, but I can't figure out how to get it in the service worker file when I get the push notification?

**client.js**

```
pushManager.subscribe({ userVisibleOnly: true }).then(({ endpoint }) => {
  const registrationId = endpoint.split('https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/')[1];
  // How do I get this registrationId in service-worker.js below?  
});
```

**service-worker.js**

```
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
  // I'd like to make a request to server to get the notification data, but I need the registrationId for that. How do I get registration id here?
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the [`ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope), you can get the effective [`ServiceWorkerRegistration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope), which in turns exposes the [`PushManager`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager), which *then* gives you a [`getSubscription()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager/getSubscription) method, which returns a `Promise` that resolves with the current subscription.

There are a lot of layers to follow, but the actual code is fairly straightforward:

```
self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(subscription => {
  // Do something with subscription.endpoint
});
```